# HTTPS doesn't work with Safari

Tags: ssl, https, safari

I have an EC2 instance with Apache as webserver (and Wildfly as app-server, although I'm not sure it has anything to do with this issue). In front of EC2 I have a load balancer which terminates HTTPS and applies the SSL cert.

Both HTTP and HTTPS works fine in Chrome, but unfortunately not in Safari. Accessing http://test.papereed.com works fine, but accessing https://test.papereed.com gives the error

```
"Safari can't open the page. The error is "The operation couldn't be completed. Protocol error" (NSPOSIXErrorDomain:100)"
```

I've looked in /etc/httpd/logs/error_log and /etc/httpd/logs/access_log and also in the Safari console without finding any hint to solving the problem. And that's about how far my knowledge goes :-( Any hints how to trace this issue would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

curl (if compiled with HTTP/2 support) exhibits the same problem but shows the reason:

> http2 error: Invalid HTTP header field was received: frame type: 1, stream: 1, name: [upgrade], value: [h2,h2c]

It looks like your server is offering an upgrade to HTTP/2 even though the connection is already done with HTTP/2 - which makes no sense. Not only that, it is explicitly forbidden. From [RFC 7540 section 8.1.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-8.1.2.2):

> An endpoint MUST NOT
> generate an HTTP/2 message containing connection-specific header
> fields; any message containing connection-specific header fields **MUST
> be treated as malformed** (Section 8.1.2.6).... connection-
> specific header fields, such as Keep-Alive, Proxy-Connection,
> Transfer-Encoding, and **Upgrade**

It looks for me a bug since Apache should not send this header with HTTP/2.

My guess is that you have a configuration like this

```
Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
```

Given that browsers do not support HTTP/2 without TLS anyway and that no Upgrade header is needed with HTTP/2 over TLS I recommend that you replace this configuration with

```
Protocols h2 http/1.1
```

This disables support for the unneeded HTTP/2 without TLS but should hopefully get rid of the Upgrade header this way since this is only needed for upgrading from plain HTTP to plain HTTP/2.

EDIT: according to the comment by the OP changing the `Protocols` configuration did not help. It was necessary to explicitly work around this behavior (i.e. bug) of `mod_http2` by deleting the `Upgrade` header:

```
Header unset Upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you! I indeed had the following config:

`# Enable HTTP/2 by default
# https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#protocols
<IfModule mod_http2.c>
    Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
</IfModule>`

Following your recommendation and changing to `Protocols h2 http/1.1` did not remove the upgrade header, so instead I kept the Protocols line as is and added the following: `Header unset Upgrade` to remove the header.
Can't say I'm 100% on top of what/why happens here but now it works fine in Safari too :-)

Comment: @jola: thanks for the feedback. I've included it into the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a Safari issue rather than an AWS / SSL issue. The search for that error gets many, many results on Google.

Everything checks out with the website according to the [SSL Shopper test](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://test.papereed.com/) and [SSL Labs Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=test.papereed.com&hideResults=on&latest).

I found [this possible solution](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7612610) to the problem.

> The solution was to go into Safari Preferences, under Privacy and list
>   all Details. This provided a log of all sites where cookies, etc had
>   been used. I found the Weather Network domain page and cleared all
>   content from it. I was then able to reload the Weather Network page
>   with no issues. I assume this would work for other similar singular
>   sites.

There's also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266188/nsposixerrordomain100-error-on-safari-when-try-to-open-https) which could be done with Apache.

Comment: Yes, I have googled this but not found anything that directly applies (afaiu). I've read the proposed solution for nginx but I'm not sure how/if this is applicable for apache.

Comment: Apache will no doubt be able to delete the ["Upgrade" header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/1.1_Upgrade_header), which is all Nginx is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx:
`Header unset Upgrade;`
does not work if you proxy your request,  use
`proxy_hide_header      Upgrade;`
instead.

Comment: Thanks. Helped me out with my configuration Nginx and Apache. Without `proxy_hide_header Upgrade;` i could access `https://my.example.com/gallery/` with Chrome but not with `Safari` and not with `curl`. `curl -4 --http2 -I -v https://my.example.com/gallery/` reported `* http2 error: Invalid HTTP header field was received: frame type: 1, stream: 1, name: [upgrade], value: [h2,h2c] * HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly: PROTOCOL_ERROR (err 1)` but after setting `proxy_hide_header` it is working.

Answer (score 0):

After I set following in Apache directives:

```
Header unset Upgrade
```

and following in NGinx directive:

```
proxy_hide_header Upgrade;
```

The problem with safari went away.